# Is there a bug in the election notifications for 2021?

Tags: bug, status-completed, election, notifications

I saw the following in my notification box:

[image]

However when I click on the message, the page shows this:

[image]

There's a slight timestamp difference because of the time it took me to write this post & take screenshots, but they're basically the same. The first one is announcing the need for more candidates and the second gives the election results. It seems like something doesn't add up there. Is this a bug, or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: This has recently happened again on the Ebooks election — it is being looked into, and we'll provide updates once we have some.

Comment: I'm just updating the tag to [status-completed], per Brian Nickel's answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The bug that caused this has been fixed.

When an election hits the primary date there were three scenarios that could happen:

- If there aren't more nominees than spots, and *the nomination phase hasn't been extended*, it gets extended.
- Otherwise, if there are enough candidates to warrant a primary, it goes to primary.
- Otherwise, it skips straight to the election phase.

There was a bug in the logic for checking that the nomination phase hadn't been extended, which caused it to always return false at the point where we were making this decision, keeping the nominations going indefinitely.

I don't know exactly what happened in this case, but I believe the election got extended a second time, a CM got an email about it, and the CM raced to the site to click cancel.

Two fixes have been implemented:

1. The check for if the election has been extended has been fixed.
2. If we've already extended the election once and we hit the primary date, we automatically cancel the election.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there is indeed a bug, or at least an unforseen confluence of events. There were two positions available but only one candidate, so the election went straight from the nomination phase to the results phase. The notification happens when the phase changes but the message is the text from the beginning of when the nomination period was extended.